Workers are activated but not receiving jobs to process
We are using camunda zeebe 8.4 with springboot. We are using the streams to receive the jobs in java application and then process the same and return the response back to zeebe.
We can see in zeebe simple monitor that the jobs are activated but the worker has not started processing the job and it gets stuck for indefinitely.
Can anyone suggest what can be the possible reasons of this indefinite stuck of job?
Code snippet :
@JobWorker(type="test-worker")
public WorkerProcess processTask(final ActivatedJob job){
// do something ....
// responseMap is the output of processing done above.


zeebeClient.newCompleteCommand(job.getKey()
           .variables(responseMap)
           .send()
           .join();

return responseMap;
}```


Have you checked to see if your workers are connected to Zeebe? Have you checked that type is test-worker in the process definition?

Yes, workers are connected to zeebe. I checked by hitting localhost:9600/actuator/jobstreams endpoint and can see this worker.

Have you checked that type is test-worker in the process definition?

Yes, the worker type was correct.

There is some issue with grpc cilent that we were using in our application. Upgrading it to latest version solved it.
